# Android :Notification Error on music Player.?

Tags: android, android-service, android-statusbar

> I'm developing a music player with Service. Сurrently focusing on
>   Notifications and Buttons...
>
> Now I have buttons on Notification bar Play, Next, Previous.. I want
>   to display pause button if media is playing & play Button if not
>   playing...

**The Error is That when i Added the If Condition inside the Notification .addction it is Showing RED lines..**

I had done the code it is Showing Error...

The Service Code is ...

Foreground.java (Class name)..

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";
    public static boolean IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = false;
    final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            showNotification();
            //-------------------------------------------

            try{
                //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3
                mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/downloadedfile.mp3");

                mp.prepare();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


            mp.start();


            //-------------------------------------
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Previous!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PAUSE_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");


            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Play!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Next!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void showNotification() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        pauseIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PAUSE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppauseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------


        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                nextIntent, 0);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.aa);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("TutorialsFace Music Player")
                .setTicker("TutorialsFace Music Player")
                .setContentText("My song")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.aa)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous",
                        ppreviousIntent)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent)
                }
        else{
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause",
                            pplayIntent)
                }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                        pnextIntent).build();
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Detroyed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Used only in case if services are bound (Bound Services).
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code I added is Put Inside the Line.....

Can anyone Suggest me the Exact code or Displayig play and pause button Simultaneoisly ?? Thank you

Comment: Hello, what exact error do you have? Your play/pause button icon is not updating? Or addAction method underlines with Api version error?

Comment: It is showing Red lines when i add if condition in between the .addAction.

Comment: I want to suggest you to use completely custom view. 1) You can do any view, what you want, 2) You will support <20 api versions

Comment: Can u suggest how i can edit the code i given

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need to use custom view for media player. [Here](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/) here is a tutorial, how you can do that. **In short:** you need to use:

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
notification.contentView = views;
notification.bigContentView = bigViews;
```

to provide **custom and expanded custom views**.

Next you need to update your notification not only when you start to showing it, but any time, when you press *play* or *pause* buttons. So you need to change:

```
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PAUSE_ACTION)) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Play!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

On

```
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PAUSE_ACTION)) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Pause");
    mp.pause();
    showNotification();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Pause!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
    mp.start();
    showNotification();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Play!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Something like that. Hope you got main idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put a semi colon before the if and then use the notification object to set the action as follow :

if(mp.isPlaying())                    notification.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent);
else
notification .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause",
                            pplayIntent);

I suppose this would do your work